# Can DNS over HTTPS that works for WiFi be modified to work with Android cellular data tethering over USB?

Tags: macos, network, dns, android, cellular-carriers

I have configured DNS over HTTPS based on these guides:
[How to implement DNS-Over-HTTPS](https://bendews.com/posts/implement-dns-over-https/) and [Setting up DNS over HTTPS on macOS](https://blog.virtualwolf.org/setting-up-dns-over-https-on-macos/).

This works fine over Wi-Fi with the DNS Servers set as `127.0.0.1` and `::1`:

[image: System preferences 1]

It also works using the [HoRNDIS](https://github.com/jwise/HoRNDIS) USB tethering driver if I connect my Android phone to Wi-Fi and share that connection via USB tethering.

However if sharing cellular data it does not work - I can resolve nothing on my Mac.  I must add the standard Cloudflare addresses (`1.1.1.1`, `1.0.0.1`, `2606:4700:4700::1111` and `2606:4700:4700::100`) and then DNS lookup works fine (but it is not using HTTPS which I want).

[image: System preferences 2]

**Question**

Is my set-up on macOS wrong/incomplete or is the ISP (the sim is from Tunisian provider [Ooredoo](http://www.ooredoo.tn/particuliers/offre-a-carte/Flexi-25Go-et-55Go)) somehow blocking DoH?  How can I tell?

I don't care particularly what the phone does with its own DNS lookups and am not asking about that. I would just like to somehow use DoH with cellular data from macOS (if it is possible) so hopefully this question is on-topic.

I don't have an iPhone to test but if that works for someone it would be an acceptable solution - as would anything else - but it would be good to confirm where the blockage lies.

---

**Current Configuration**

MacBook Pro mid 2014.  Firewall is set to on in *System Preferences* and blocking all incoming connections, [Lulu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) set to allow outbound connections for *cloudflared* and standard Apple programs.  There is no change if both are turned off.

**dnsmasq**

built from source obtained from [thekelleys.org.uk](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), this is my config file:

```
A1398% cat /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1
#port=0
server=127.0.0.1#54
no-resolv
```

service plist is based on [homebrew-core/Formula/dnsmasq.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/dnsmasq.rb):

```
A1398% cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/hali.dnsmasq.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>hali.dnsmasq</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq</string>
      <string>--keep-in-foreground</string>
      <string>-C</string>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**cloudflared**

downloaded as per the [documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/access/cli/installing-cli-tool/) using:

```
curl https://bin.equinox.io/c/VdrWdbjqyF/cloudflared-stable-darwin-amd64.tgz | tar xzC /usr/local/bin
```

config file:

```
A1398% cat /usr/local/etc/cloudflared/config.yml
no-autoupdate: false
proxy-dns: true
proxy-dns-port: 54
proxy-dns-upstream:
  - https://1.1.1.1/dns-query
  - https://1.0.0.1/dns-query
  - https://2606:4700:4700::1111/dns-query
  - https://2606:4700:4700::1001/dns-query
```

service plist created by `sudo cloudflared service install`:

```
A1398% cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.cloudflare.cloudflared.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.cloudflare.cloudflared</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/cloudflared</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Library/Logs/com.cloudflare.cloudflared.out.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Library/Logs/com.cloudflare.cloudflared.err.log</string>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
        <integer>20</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I got it to work in a Catalina VM with a USB-tethered iPhone (cellular data), but I **really** don't know if this will be a valid answer...It's really hacky because I don't get a  configurable interface in the network prefs for the iPhone-USB network device (your 2nd screenshot).

Comment: @klanomath - I'm by no means an expert on this but I *think* that `dig @127.0.0.1 -p 54 google.com` tests *cloudflared* and `dig google.com @127.0.0.1` tests *dnsmasq*.  You can then visit [DNS leak test](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/) from a browser and assuming you haven't defined *Cloudflare* elsewhere and it is being used then it is probably working.  Of course perhaps iPhone USB tethering doesn't let you set DNS - I don't know about that.

Comment: Already done that ;-) (except the leak test - I used http://en.conn.internet.nl/connection instead). It wasn't possible to modify anything with the GUI but with `networksetup ...` I set another DNS server (127.0.0.1). I have to check all this with a real machine again because I don't know how a VMware macOS VM (+an old tethered iPhone) alters things...